# Route to last active child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm trying to implement a conceptually simple problem, but it's turning out to be a real pain.

I have nested routes that look like this:

```
-Foo
    -foo1 (default)
    -foo2
-Bar
    -bar1 (default)
        -fubar1 (default)
        -fubar2
    -bar2
```

`Foo` and `Bar` are links in a navbar. Their direct child routes are in a sidebar, on separate pages. Whenever I route to a navbar link, I want their last active child to be routed to.

Example routing:

1. User visits `Foo`, `foo1` is activated.
2. User visits `foo2`.
3. User visits `Bar`, `bar1` is activated.
4. User visits `bar2`.
5. User visits `Foo`, `foo2` is activated. (last active child of `Foo` is routed to)
6. User visits `Bar`, `bar2` is activated. (last active child of `Bar` is routed to)

My current solution involves component navigation guards:

```
export default {
    ...,
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            let lastActive = vm.$store.state.lastActivePaths[vm.$options.name]
            if (lastActive) {
                next(lastActive)
            } else {
                next()
            }
        })
    },
    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
        this.$store.commit(SET_LAST_ACTIVE_PATH, {
            routeName: this.$options.name,
            path: from.path
        })
        next()
    },
}
```

Vuex:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        lastActivePaths: {},
    },
    mutations: {
        [SET_LAST_ACTIVE_PATH](state, payload) {
            let { routeName, path } = payload
            Vue.set(state.lastActivePaths, routeName, path)
        },
    },
})
```

It "works", but it requires logic in 2 different places and can quickly become a mess. Is there a simpler solution?